# How to create a GraphQL resolver that can ‘complete’ a type

Tags: graphql

Let’s say we have a mutation that returns an array of objects with only the property `id`. To “complete” this type we have to create a resolver for every single property of this object.

Instead I’d like to be able to create a resolver that can complete an object.

Below an example of a query that sends a list of heroes and a mutation to favorite one. The resolver of the `mutation setFavorite(id)` returns only a list of `IDs`.

```
type Query {
  heroes(first: Int = 10) [Hero]
}

type Hero {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
}

type Mutation {
  setFavorite(id: ID!): [Hero]
}
```

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    heroes(_, {first}, {heroes}) {
      return heroes.get({first});
    }
  },
  Mutation: {
    setFavorite(_, {id}, {favorites}) {
      await favorites.setFavorite(id);
      return favorites.getAll(); // <<<< these are only IDs
    }
  }
}
```

### Is it possible to create a resolver, that "completes" a type?

```js
const resolvers = {
  Hero: {
//  vvvvvv something like this
    __type(parent, _, {heroes}) {
      if (parent.id) {
        return heroes.getOne({id: parent.id});
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible directly but could be done with JS Proxies. This would be jumping through hoops a lot though and the only benefit I can see would be to not call the resolver when only the ID field is requested. There are different ways of solving this though. Can you explain why you would not simply map over the id values in the mutation resolver? `return favorites.getAll().then(ids => Promise.all(ids.map(id => heroes.getOne({ id }))));`.

Comment: A better question would be why a method like `favorites.getAll` is returning only IDs in the first place. If you genuinely need just the IDs elsewhere in your code, it might make sense to simply expose two separate methods -- `getAll` to get all favorites and `getAllIds` to just get the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Only fields are *resolved*, so you can only write resolvers for fields, not types. Your options are:

- Change methods like `getAll` to actually return instances of the models in question instead of just returning the IDs.
- Map the returned IDs to model instances inside each resolver.
- Write a resolver for each child field:

```
const resolvers = {
  Hero: {
    title: (id, args, ctx) => {
      const hero = await ctx.dataloaders.hero.findById(id)
      return hero.title
    },
    someOtherField: (id, args, ctx) => {
      const hero = await ctx.dataloaders.hero.findById(id)
      return hero.someOtherField
    },
  },
}
```

Notice that we use [dataloader](https://github.com/graphql/dataloader) in this example. This lets us batch the calls to `findById` and avoids calling the method twice for the same id. You shouldn't use this pattern without DataLoader; otherwise you'll end up with unnecessary additional calls to your database.